# RoleManagerModule and RolePrincipal object

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, roles

According to my book, if role management is enabled, then `RoleManagerModule` creates the security context of the user by assigning `RolePrincipal` object to the `HttpRequest.User`. But isn’t security context  already created (thus principal object being assigned to `HttpContext.User` ) by `FormsAuthenticationModule`, which is called prior to `RoleManagerModule` being called?

I’m asking this, because in the following code principal object assigned to `HttpRequest.User` already exists, even though `RoleManagerModule` has not yet been called:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Roles.Enabled)
    {
        //here we subscribe user to a role via Roles.AddUserToRole()
    }       
}
```

So is principal object, created by `FormsAuthenticationModule` and assigned to `HttpRequest.User`, later replaced by `RolePrincipal` object (created by `RoleManagerModule`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/tutorial-11-cs.aspx):

> If the Roles framework is enabled, the  RoleManagerModule HTTP Module steps in after the FormsAuthenticationModule  and identifies the authenticated user’s roles during the  PostAuthenticateRequest event, which fires after the AuthenticateRequest  event. If the request is from an authenticated user, the RoleManagerModule overwrites the GenericPrincipal object created by the FormsAuthenticationModule and replaces it with a  RolePrincipal object. The RolePrincipal class uses the Roles API to determine what roles the user belongs to.

So you're right.

Comment: Gah! My custom principal was implementing IPrincipal, not RolePrincipal, so my RoleProvider's implementation was not being used properly when handling the PostAuthenticateRequest. Big thanks for that, @bbmud!